# Solve parameter from stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

how can I solve $\rho$ from the following:

$\int_0^T dV_t = \int_0^T \kappa (\theta - V_t) dt + \int_0^T \sigma \rho \sqrt{V_t} dW_t + \int_0^T  \sigma \sqrt{1-\rho^2} \sqrt{V_t} dZ_t$,

where $W_t$ and $Z_t$ are uncorrelated Brownian motions and I know $V_t$ and all other paramaters i.e. $\sigma$, $\kappa$, $\theta$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\mathrm d\langle V,W\rangle_t=\sigma\rho\sqrt{V_t}\mathrm dt$ hence, for every $t\gt0$, $$\rho=\frac1{\sigma t}\int_0^t\frac{\mathrm d\langle V,W\rangle_s}{\sqrt{V_s}}.$$ Likewise, for every $t\gt0$, $$\sqrt{1-\rho^2}=\frac1{\sigma t}\int_0^t\frac{\mathrm d\langle V,Z\rangle_s}{\sqrt{V_s}}.$$ **Edit:** Numerically, the integral involving [the co-variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_variation) of $V$ and $W$ in the first formula translates into $$\int_0^t\frac{\mathrm d\langle V,W\rangle_s}{\sqrt{V_s}}\approx\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1{\sqrt{V_{t_k}}}\left(V_{t_k}-V_{t_{k-1}}\right)\left(W_{t_k}-W_{t_{k-1}}\right),$$ when the mesh $\|P\|$ of the partition $P=(t_k)_{0\leqslant k\leqslant n}$ of the interval $[0,t]$ goes to zero.

Comment: Maybe my question was unclear. I need a formula to get a numerical result of $\rho$. Or can I evaluate $d<V,W>_s$ numerically?

Comment: Sure, using the standard numerical scheme for co-variation processes, see Edit.

Comment: Yes, but I do not observe the Brownian itself, hence I don't know its increment $ W_t_k - W_t_{k-1} $.

Comment: With each comment, we are facing more starkly the fact that **you did not ask the question that is interesting you**. Having no interest for a career in divination, and unless you decide to state clearly what your problem is, I think it is best for me to leave things as they are.

Comment: I have found another way to numerically solve $\rho$. Thanks anyways.